# Area under curve python

Tags: python

I have a set of data points which when visualized by line graph look like this
[image]

The value on x-axis in time and value on Y axis is a number. My ultimate task is to find the integral of the graph between any input time frame.

I think I need to do two things-

1- Find a continuous function defining this line graph (orange line)

2- Then maybe use scipy.integrate library to compute the integration.

I have two questions-

1- Is this the right approach or there is any smarter way to do it?

2- How to find the function of line graph given a set of data points ? This is little different than curve fitting where we find the 'best' fit. Here I want a function defining the line graph visualized.

Any insight in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: That function looks periodic enough for you to dream of a decent Fourier transform. However, why do you need to find a continuous function first ? Why not perform directly a good numeric integration ?

Comment: You don't need to find the continuous function at all, in my opinion. Scipy.integrate can deal with these things in many different ways. You should understand them, and choose one.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, is it?  Anyway, you don't need to fit a function to your data.  You can integrate it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 5):

You cannot find any continuous function for this kind of data, it's totally irregular as the plot shows.

What you want to do is to use the [Trapezoidal Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#/media/File:Trapezium.gif). It is available as a Numpy function ([numpy.trapz](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)).

Comment: Just for completeness: or Simpson's, or Romberg's... Numerical integration is a vast sub-field.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree about the continuous function. It's possible to do numerical integration for data like this using Simpson's rule or something like it.

Since it's a time series, you could do an FFT and integrate in the frequency domain, then transform the result.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
I have time axis stored in a numpy array of dtype=datetime[ns] that looks like this-

    ['2015-03-30T12:04:05.000000000+0200',
    '2015-04-06T12:02:30.000000000+0200',
    '2015-04-06T12:03:34.000000000+0200',
    ..........................
    '2015-05-11T11:05:16.000000000+0200']

Why do you advice to perform a fourier transform over it? Could'nt it be done in time domain?

Comment: Of course it can be done in the time domain.  You'll have to do some work to turn those timestamps into something that will let you do time integration.  Ditch the GMT for starters.

Comment: Can you suggest some functions/library for this?

Comment: No, this is a data scrubbing issue.  You need to scrub your data to get it into the form that a NumPy numerical integrator can deal with.  I'm guessing you'll have two arrays: t[n] for time variables and f[n] for function value at the time point.